# Reading csv without specific type

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I want to read csv file and save to list or array or anything, but `CsvHelper` demands to save it as collection of specific type. Problem is my csv has so many columns, that mapping it to custom class will take a few weeks.

How can I just read it without saving as specific type? Accessing specific values with thing like `row[1][2]` is more than enough for me.

Comment: CSVHelper does all the mapping, you just need to write up the class - *that* cant take weeks.  That said, CSVHelper also has some primitive type methods to read raw data as strings.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp that csv has like 250 columns, this is overkill. There has to be a way to just read it without saving as collection of specific type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add it to a datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int rowCount = 0;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    if (rowCount == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string col in splitArray)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(splitArray);
                    }
                }

            }
 

        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the answer is to not use CsvHelper for these situations.

Comment: No, this is bad advice. Splitting on commas is not guaranteed to work for all standard CSVs (see RFC4180). It *might* work for your data, but that is no guarantee that it will handle future data.

Comment: But if the OPs input is always comma than it will work.

Comment: @jdweng Go read the RFC. Splitting by comma (or tab or bar) is not the correct way to parse a CSV. You don't know enough about their file to assert that this will work.

Comment: @MarkPflug in my case it will work. But I'm open for solutions that work 24/7.

Comment: @MarkPflug : It will 99.99% of the time.  Who cares when it doesn't work 0.00% of the time.  It will work 100.00% of the time for this OP.